# Is there a performance penalty for returning a new struct in a getter?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I have a public getter returning a struct that never changes:

```
public Vector3 Center => new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
```

It's not static, because it may change in the future, but for now it's always the same value.

Is there a performance penalty for always creating a new Vector3 (a struct), instead of doing something like this:

```
static readonly Vector3 half = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
public Vector3 Center => half;
```

I understand that structs are returned by value, so the value copy is always going to happen. I also know that any difference in performance is going to be minimal. I just wonder about the additional construction. Is this maybe something the compiler can recognize and optimize?

Comment: The difference will be the evaluation of the expressions for the parameters of the constructor as well as the code in the constructor, vs. making a memory copy of the original structure. Opinions follows: Yes, there is a cost. No, it's not much. Yes, it will be measurable. No it will not be noticably.

Comment: You might have a look at [ref struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#ref-struct) concept

Comment: it's a small dereference, it might or might have an impact, but probably  small. For performances question, I'd recommend you benchmark both versions, with amount of data / stress that you can reasonably get in production. That would definitely tell if this has an impact or not in your case.

Comment: Yes.  Calling a constructor for a class always take time to construct.  Creating a link/reference to an existing class is always quicker.   The penalty is based on the number of times you use the object.  If you use the object only once than there is no penalty.  If you use the object 100 times then you will be calling the constructor 100 times instead of just once.

Comment: @jdweng It's not a class, it's a struct.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Unfortunately, I do not have access to the implementation of that struct. But it's an interesting concept, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a computational cost every time you new up an object. The extent to which it  costs you is subject to debate.